# I have a problem with 'window.js_obj' in brython

Tags: javascript, python, json, jsobject, brython

I'm currently facing a problem with **window.js_obj**
I have a JSObject obtain through an API and jQuery but when I try to convert the gotten JSObject into a proper Python Dict, it seems like there is no module called js_obj into window.
Here is what I wrote to convert the thing:

```
userInfo_request = window.js_obj.to_dict(userInfo_request)
```

(userInfo_request is my variable containing the JSObject as stated when I input

```
print(type(userInfo_request))
```

```
<class 'JSObject'>
```

The error that I get in my browser's console is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  module __main__ line 31
    userInfo_request = window.js_obj.to_dict(userInfo_request)
AttributeError: no attribute js_obj for [object Window]
```

If someone could help me it would be super cool
Thanks in advance

I'm using Python 3 and Brython 3.8.7 (the latest version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
dir(window)
# Or
hasattr(window, 'js_obj')
```

to check if the `window` object has the `js_obj` attribute or not at the runtime.

Comment: Thank you!! It helped me a lot finding where the module actually was (it got changed in an update)

Answer (score 1):

I understood the problem.
In fact, I think it was changed in an update (but we should change the documentations) and the js_obj.to_dict got changed into JSObject.to_dict in the module “javascript” instead of “window”